# I am getting an error while regenerating the static-content in Magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2.4.5

I am getting an error while regenerating the static content. In Admin dashboard links are not working.
Can delete the var folder and pub/static folder and regenerate content?
Or
How can I fix this problem?
I am getting this problem after installing Stripe plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run below CLI commands:-

```
rm -rf generated/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed*
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following CLI commands

```
rm -rf [magento_root]/generated/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs first. System.log, exception.log